# mysql_fetch_array() não mostra todos os registros

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, eu estou com problemas, em minha tabela da base de dados tenho 3 registros, uso o código abaixo para buscá-los:

```
public function buscarMateriaProva($codigoProva){
    $query  = " SELECT  codigoMateria, codigoProva, quantidadeQuestao
                FROM    materiasProvas
                WHERE   codigoProva = ".$codigoProva;

    //se for executado
    if($res = mysql_query($query)){
        $row    = mysql_fetch_row($res);
        $nr     = (int)mysql_num_rows($res);

        #se houver registro povoa o obj, senão retorna falso
        if($nr === 0){
            return false;
        } else {
            return $res;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Neste caso, o $nr tem valor 3, pois são 3 registros, até ai tudo bem.

O valor retorna para o meu arquivo onde monto a estrutura utilizando mysql_fetch_array():

$resMateriaProva = $materiaProva->buscarMateriaProva($codigo);

```
while($arrayMateriaProva = mysql_fetch_array($resMateriaProva)){
    print_r($arrayMateriaProva);        
}
```

Ele retorna os 3 registros, normal, mas só exibe os 2 últimos, ignorando o primeiro registro.

Alguém sabe qual o erro?

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: Mysql é suscetível a invasões, porque você não atualiza para pdo ou mysqli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque você não substitui o mysql_fetch_array por mysql_fetch_row.

ficaria assim:

```
while($arrayMateriaProva = mysql_fetch_array($resMateriaProva)){
print_r($arrayMateriaProva);        
}
```

e você não precisa desta linha

```
$row    = mysql_fetch_row($res);
```

Pelo visto você não está utilizando a variável, e bem provável que seja ela que esta removendo o primeiro resultado. Tenta comentar ela e testa, se der certo nem precisa trocar o mysql_fetch_array. Isso porque o mysql_fetch_row pega uma linha por vez, e ao utiliza-lo você já remove o primeiro resultado e retorna o resto da consulta. Como você não utiliza a variável $row você não percebe que recebeu o primeiro resultado. Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: Valeu, funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar, foi um prazer. Mas trago outra sugestão, da uma olhadinha em PDO, ele facilita muito na parte de gerenciamento com o banco de dados e já trata os parâmetros.